# How to pass values from an array to a drop down list in a certain cell (not combo list) in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pass values from an array to a drop down list in a specifc cell.
Say I have an array which contains the values 1,2,3 and I want cell A1 to contain a drop down list with these value, Is there any way I can do this? 
I'm trying to achive this without having to first assign these value to different cells and use data validation. (And as stated in the title, I don't want to use combo boxes or user forms)

Comment: If you don't want a combo box, what other kind of drop down lists ARE there?  IDGI

Comment: Oh, perhaps I used the wrong term, I thought combo boxes were the  ActiveX drop down list controler. What I need is a drop down list inside a cell, just like the drop down lists created through Data Validation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a way of doing it:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array("1", "2", "3")

Range("A" & 1).Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=myArray(0) & "," & myArray(1) & "," & myArray(2)
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: This answer is would be hugely improved by: 1) Replacing `Formula1:=myArray(0) & "," & myArray(1) & "," & myArray(2)` with `Formula1:=Join(MyArray, ",")`, especially if the validation dropdown list is long. 2) Deleting `Range("A" & 1).Select` and then replacing `With Selection.Validation` with `With Range("A1").Validation`. Don't use `Selection` when you can simply pass the specific range object instead. And don't concatenate strings in the range object parameter unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of ways, same result,

```
Sub DataVal1()
    With Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3"
    End With
End Sub
Sub DataVal2()
    Dim x As String
    x = "1,2,3"
    With Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:=x
    End With
End Sub
```