# Trying to Translate Data Validation in from VBA to VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I have some code where I am trying to build a data validation box. I have setup on how I want it in VBA, but I am unsure on how this is supposed to look in VB.Net

I am using this as a guide from Davy C from [How to pass values from an array to a drop down list in a certain cell (not combo list) in excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208342/how-to-pass-values-from-an-array-to-a-drop-down-list-in-a-certain-cell-not-comb)

The raw data validation code can be shown here:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array("1", "2", "3")

Range("A" & 1).Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=myArray(0) & "," & myArray(1) & "," & myArray(2)
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Do you want to validate something in Excel or something in a Windows Form (for example a TextBox)?

Comment: I am trying to do this in Excel

Comment: You question is confusing, excel is VBA not VB.Net

Comment: I'm trying to translate my code that is written in VBA to VB.Net @CruleD